# Vector spaces - decide if $U=V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U,V$ be sub-spaces of $\mathbb R^3$.
$$U=\text{span}\{(1,2,0),(0,1,-1)\}$$
$$V=\text{span}\{(2,1,3),(-1,0,-2)\}$$
Decide if $U=V$.
According to the results, they should equal to each other. But how to prove that?
Should I use linear combination somehow? 
Maybe $\alpha_1(1,2,0)+\alpha_2(0,1,-1)=\beta_1(2,1,3)+\beta_2(-1,0,2)$ ?
Since I really don't know how to solve it, I'll appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Show that $(1,2,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ are in $V$ and do the same for members of $V$

Comment: Take the cross product of the vectors in U.  This will give you a vector that is not in U. Do the same thing for V.  Do you get parallel vectors?  What would that suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the dimension of the span of a set of vectors is the rank of the matrix build by those vectors. Now just compute the rank of the matrix build by all four vectors.

Comment: You mean I should use this theorem? $dim(U\cap V) = dim U + dim V - dim (U + V)$ ?

Comment: Just keep it simple and stupid: obviously $\dim(U)=2$. Now what conclusion may you draw if $\dim(U+V)$ is $2$  as well?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that both $\;(2,1,3)\,,\,(-1,0,-2)\in\text{Span}\,\{(1,2,0),\,(0,1,-1)\}\;$ , and now check both spaces are of dimension two.

Answer (score 2):

Since $u_1$ and $u_2$ in $U = \text{span}\left\{ u_1 , u_2 \right\}$ are clearly linearly independent, you have $\text{dim}\,U = 2$, the same reasoning applies to $V= \text{span}\left\{ v_1 , v_2 \right\}$, yielding $\text{dim}\,V = 2$ as well.

Now check whether $u_1,u_2 \in V$. If so, then not only $u_1$ and $u_2$, but also all of their linear combinations - and thus all elements of $U$ - are in $V$, since $V$ is a linear subspace.

Either combine this with the dimension argument above, or also check whether $v_1,v_2 \in U$.

Answer (score 1):

*Should I use linear combination somehow?*

Yes, the approach that you have started works:

Your equality
$$\alpha_1(1,2,0)+\alpha_2(0,1,-1)=\beta_1(2,1,3)+\beta_2(-1,0,2)$$
is equivalent to
$$\left\{\begin{align}\alpha_1&=2\beta_1-\beta_2\\
2\alpha_1+\alpha_2&=\beta_1\\
-\alpha_2&=3\beta_1+2\beta_2
\end{align}\right.\tag{1}$$

For $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ given, the linear system $(1)$ in the unknowns $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ has solution. In other words, any element of $U$ is an element of $V$.

Conversely, for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ given, the linear system $(1)$ in the unknowns $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ has solution. In other words, any element of $V$ is an element of $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you do use linear combinations to prove that, but not the way your are thinking about it. Observe that, in general, if $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a subespace of $V$  and $v_1,...,v_n \in V$ then
$$span\{ v_1,...,v_n \} \subset W \iff \{v_1,..., v_n \} \subset W$$ they are both very intuitive and easy to prove (try to do them yourself, and let me know if you have any trouble proving that).

So we want to prove that equality, so we should be able to prove that, $U \subset V$ and $V \subset U$. The first inclusion will happen if and only if $\{ ( 1,2,0 ) , ( 0,1,-1 ) \} \subset span\{ ( 2,1,3 ), ( -1,0,-2) \} $, which, in terms of linear combinations means that the first two vectors are linear combinations of the last two. The other inclusion is analogous.